# pgSQL query error

Tags: sql, postgresql

i tried using this query:

"SELECT * FROM guests WHERE event_id=".$id." GROUP BY member_id;"

and I'm getting this error:

ERROR: column "guests.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

can anyone explain how i can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't Group By without letting the Select know what to take, and how to group.
Try

```
SELECT guests.member_id FROM guests WHERE event_id=".$id." GROUP BY member_id;
```

IF you need to get more info from this table about the guests, you'll need to add it to the Group By.

Plus, it seems like your select should actually be

```
SELECT guests.id FROM guests WHERE event_id=".$id." GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of the columns used in a `group by` query needs to be specifically called out (ie, don't do `SELECT * FROM ...`), as you need to use them in some sort of aggregate function (min/max/sum/avg/count/etc) or be part of the `group by` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT instrument, detector, min(date_obs), max(date_obs)
FROM observations
WHERE observatory='SOHO'
GROUP BY instrument, detector;
```